# Which class in ruby is parent of all class?

Tags: ruby

I had thought that `Object` is an ancestor of all classes, but I tried something which made me confused.

```
Object.superclass # => BasicObject
Object.superclass.superclass # => nil
Object.superclass.superclass.superclass # => undefined method error since nil is not a class
Object.superclass.superclass.class # => Nilclass
Object.superclass.superclass.class.superclass # => Object
```

Except for `nil`, everything has a superclass, and `nil` is an instance of `NilClass`, so it cannot have super class method. How one can get `Object` as superclass of `Object`?

Comment: `BasicObject` is the topmost class, which is an instance of `Class`, which extends `Object`, which extends `BasicObject`... lol

Comment: Thats really weird inheritance, lol

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: That has nothing to do with inheritance. You *really* got things mixed up here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`superclass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-superclass)is a method of `Class`. Now `NilClass` inherits from `Object`. But the class `Object` have no chance to inherit the class `Class` methods.

See below from the [`Documentaion`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html)

```
Classes, modules, and objects are interrelated. In the diagram that follows, the vertical arrows represent inheritance,
and the parentheses meta-classes. All metaclasses are instances of the class `Class'.


                         +---------+             +-...
                         |         |             |
         BasicObject-----|-->(BasicObject)-------|-...
             ^           |         ^             |
             |           |         |             |
          Object---------|----->(Object)---------|-...
             ^           |         ^             |
             |           |         |             |
             +-------+   |         +--------+    |
             |       |   |         |        |    |
             |    Module-|---------|--->(Module)-|-...
             |       ^   |         |        ^    |
             |       |   |         |        |    |
             |     Class-|---------|---->(Class)-|-...
             |       ^   |         |        ^    |
             |       +---+         |        +----+
             |                     |
obj--->OtherClass---------->(OtherClass)-----------...
```

Yes that's correct as `nil` being an object of `NilClass`,which in turn inherits `Object` which is on top of the class `Class`. Thus `Nilclass` couldn't inherit `superclass` method.

```
Object.superclass.superclass #=> nil
nil.superclass #=> undefined method error since nil is not a class
```

Comment: Yeah I have also tried same, is it not weired that object of some other class which inherits Object is superclass of Object. eg nil

Answer (score 5):

From [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html)

> BasicObject is the parent class of all classes in Ruby

The superclass of Object is BasicObject, and BasicObject *does not have a superclass*. The standard placeholder for non-existent things is nil, so BasicObject.superclass returns nil.

It so happens that nil is an instance of the class NilClass, which is a subclass of Object. This does not mean that NilClass is a superclass of BasicObject or that Object is a superclass of Object.

Comment: Yeah that is what sounds weird to me, the supeclass for BasicObject is nil and nil is object of NilClass which has Object as its parent and BasicObject is parent for Object.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: Do you even read what people write here? You are posting the same comment over and over...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Sorry if i missed something. Ok i got your point, but this doesn't seem to be correct way of representing superclass. In fact if Basic Object is topmost in order that BasicObject should not have supeclass function, i.e. my point

Answer (score 4):

You don't get "Object as superclass of Object". What you get is "Object as superclass of Nilclass".

Comment: Yeah but nil which is object of NilClass is superclass of Object. How it can be correct?

Comment: No, nil is returned as the superclass of BasicObject because BasicObject has no superclass!

Comment: `nil` isn't the superclass of `Object` or `BasicObject`. `BasicObject` has no superclass, that's exactly the reason why `BasicObject.superclass` returns `nil`, i.e. nothing, nada, zero. Please also see [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass): "returns nil when the given class hasn’t a parent class"